# Windows Server 2008 R2 Core has no network adapters on a fresh install

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-core

After the install there is only a Loopback-Pseudo-Interface shown when I execute

```
netsh interface ipv4 show interfaces
```

Do I have to enable the real adapter explicitly or does the server has no appropriate driver for the network adapter?

Comment: You should update your question to detail the server make and model, or at least the network card model.

Answer (score 2):

As jscott said, you really need to provide more info (make/model) of the system and the NIC. That being said, if this is server class hardware and you just ran the install directly off a Microsoft retail/Volume license media, it's a pretty good bet that you need to get the driver for the NIC. If you have drivers you can install them in core using the pnputil.exe

```
pnputil -i -a <path to .inf file>
```

edit: wow - just realized this question was from 2011 but only edited again today. Somehow, I doubt this user is coming back to mark this as answered..

Answer (score 0):

Try "netsh interface set interface name="Local Area Connection" admin=ENABLED"
just to see if can ressurect the adapter. If not, it would seem they are not appropriated  from the bios.